# Grand total and total quantity not showing adding for all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Script:

```
 function subTotal3(param)
  {

        var product_quantity = 0;
        var product_price = 0;
        var gst_amount = 0;

        var sub_total = 0;
        var total_qty = 0; 
        var grand_total = 0;
        var splitty;
        var unit_price;

       $('input[id=qty_'+param+']').each( function( k, v ) {

           /*starts here*/
           product_quantity = parseInt ( $(this).val() ) ? parseInt ( $(this).val() ) : 0;
           product_price = $(this).parent().prev().text()? $(this).parent().prev().text():0;
          /*ends here*/

           splitty = product_price.split('RM');
           unit_price = splitty[1];
           sub_total = parseFloat (unit_price * product_quantity);

           $(this).parent().next().val(sub_total);
           $(this).parent().next().text(sub_total);

            total_qty += product_quantity;

            grand_total += sub_total;

        });

        alert(total_qty);
        $('.qty_1').text(total_qty);
        $('.total').text(grand_total);
  }
```

This is the output (Note values under total):

[image]

Values under 'total' showing the currently selected items total quantity and subtotal. Supposedly, it should show total for both items.

I guessed, declaring `var total_qty = 0;`, `var grand_total = 0;` causing it thus I declared them without assigning value `0` then it shows `NaN` for `Amount`. I tried placing `total_qty += product_quantity;` outside $.each loop, but the same problem. How do I add the total quantity and total amount at total, please?

Comment: @Lola, exactly thats the problem...I replaced that with common class then specific id then it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting class on your input such as `class="qty"`. then replace `$('input[id=qty_'+param+']')` with `$('.qty')`